# 100% disk usage. what to do?

Tags: linux, disk-usage, deleted-files

```
root@vps559:/# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            960M     0  960M   0% /dev
tmpfs           195M  648K  194M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        20G   20G   82M 100% /
tmpfs           973M     0  973M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           973M     0  973M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      105M  3.4M  102M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           195M     0  195M   0% /run/user/0
```

as you can see, some folder(?) has full of files.
Where is this folder? How can I delete unwanted files?

```
/dev/sda1        20G   20G   82M 100% /
```

I tried.

```
root@vps559:/# cd /dev/sda1
-bash: cd: /dev/sda1: Not a directory
```

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/sda1` is not a directory but a block device. Easy to find out with `ls -ld /dev/sda1`.

You get the space usage by running

```
du -hx --max-depth=1 /
```